# Python regular expression findall *

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am not able to understand the following code behavior.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'been'
>>> r = re.compile(r'b(e)*')
>>> r.search(text).group()
'bee' #makes sense
>>> r.findall(text)
['e'] #makes no sense
```

I read some already existing question and answers about capturing groups and all. But still I am confused. Could someone please explain me.

Comment: Have you read the docs for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) vs. [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)? They do different things...

Comment: If you use one of them incorrectly a cat dies somewhere in the world.

Answer (score 1):

When a pattern contains a capture group, `findall` returns only the content of the capture group and no more the whole match.

If this behaviour looks strange, it can be very useful to extract easily parts of a string in a particular context (substring before or after), especially since python re module doesn't support variable length lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simplified in the [Regex Howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#performing-matches), `group` returns the string matched by the Regular Expression.

> `group()` returns the substring that was matched by the RE.

But the action of `findall` is justified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group

So you are getting the matched part of the capture group.

Some experiments include :

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(b)(e)*')
>>> r.findall(text)
[('b', 'e')]
```

Here the regex has two capturing groups, so the returned values are a list of matched groups (in tuples)